# Is it an useful inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability's space and  $(A_i)_{i \in [1,n]} \in \mathcal{A}^n$. Then we have the inequality :

$$\mathbb{P}(\bigcup \limits_{r=1}^{n}A_r)\le \min \limits_{k} \left\{\sum \limits_{r=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A_r) - \sum \limits_{r\in [1,n],\ r\neq k} \mathbb{P}(A_r \cap A_k) \right\}~.$$

Are there applications of that fact ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "useful"?

Comment: @Math1000 Do we use it to solve problems in probability and if so, what kind of exercises or statement ?